# How to check in development or production in ERB file in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, development-environment, production-environment

I want to load jQuery UI via Google CDN if in production and locally if in development. So in my application.html.erb layout, I've got to know whether I'm in production or dev. Is there a variable I can check?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

To expand a bit on Paritosh's answer, `Rails.env.production?` and `Rails.env.development?` will return true/false depending on which environment you're using.

These methods are defined in the `StringInquirer` class in the `ActiveSupport` module. See them [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/string_inquirer.rb).

Comment: Where can I see the source of these functions? must be a meta programming thing.any idea?

Comment: Yes, it is. Have a look [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/e20dd73df42d63b206d221e2258cc6dc7b1e6068/activesupport/lib/active_support/string_inquirer.rb).

Answer (score 9):

To riff off of the previous answer, you can scope your check to specific environments like so:

```
Rails.env.development?
```

where `development?` is the name of the environment you want to check.

Also something else I tend to do is if I am checking multiple environments you may want to do something like:

```
if %w(staging production).include?(Rails.env)
  # do something
end
```

Answer (score 2):

use `Rails.env`, it will give you environment you are working on.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for. It appears to return a StringInquirer. Is there a particularly way we're expected to query this object?

Comment: check @Zajn answer, it perfectly match your requirement.